# jQuery dynamic img change after Ajax request

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#" rel="39" title="Favorit entfernen?" class="add_favorit">
<img src="/maxyourhealth/assets/images/icon/bookmark_active.svg" alt="Dein Favorit" data-alt-src="/maxyourhealth/assets/images/icon/bookmark.svg" width="19" height="27">
</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('.add_favorit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var aid = $(this).attr("rel");
    var img_src = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
    var img_new = $(this).children("img").attr("data-alt-src");

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/maxyourhealth/assets/ajax/inc.favorit.php",
                data: {a1:aid},
                success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                  $(this).children("img").attr("src", img_new);
                  $(this).children("img").attr("data-alt-src", img_el);
                } 
                })
})
```

This is a script to add some articles as personal favourites. I tried to change the `img` after the ajax call but the change doesn't work.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Try adding `context: this` as one of the arguments to the ajax call.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ details this option.

Comment: Inside of the ajax the `this` changes.  I typically add `var $this = $(this);` ahead of the ajax and then use it inside the success function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the success handler of the ajax method, the value of `this` is different than what it was when you called it.  In order to make it be the same value, there are a few ways to do this.

1) Save off the this into a variable

```
var that = this;

$.ajax({
    ...
    , success: function(){
        //use 'that' in here instead of this
    }
});
```

2) Use the `context` option on the ajax method.  Ref. api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    , context: this
    , success: function(){
        //'this' will be the same inside the ajax as it was outside
    }
});
```

3) Use an arrow function (ES6 functionality)

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    , success: () => {
        //use 'this', as arrow methods do not change the value of this
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue where the context of `this` (or `$(this)`) is changed.

What you can do in this instance is use the [ES6 Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to solve this issue.

Change,

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);

    $(this).children("img").attr("src", img_new);
    $(this).children("img").attr("data-alt-src", img_el);
}
```

To,

```
// the parenthesis around 'data' can be stripped off if there is only one parameter.
success: (data) => {
    alert(data);

    $(this).children("img").attr("src", img_new);
    $(this).children("img").attr("data-alt-src", img_el);
}
```

You can also use [`context: this`](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20function) however, I try to advocate the arrow function purely because the code becomes a lot clearer and it saves you from 'code smell' by not having to define another variable which is referenced to `$(this)`.

**Reading Material & Compatibility**

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20function)

[ES6 New Features, Lexical `this`](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis)